# Matching fields in queries with or without tildes in django

Tags: django

I have a search functionality where I find objects matching text with field__icontains=text, the problem is that it wont find for example 'mecánico' if the search term is 'mecanico', I want it to match it either way, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need complicate search, may be it would be better to use some search engine - `solr`, `sphinx` or something. It is a good app for linking django with different search engines - `django-haystack`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try a `regex` lookup: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex